# Looping through arrays

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I have been learning python for the past two months, still trying to figure out how do for loops work exactly! I would like to know if what I am thinking is even possible.

So i have 2 array with random information

```
a = np.array([96.6, 93.71, 91.56, 90.24, 89.74, 90.04, 91.09, 92.82, 95.19, 98.14])

b = np.array([101.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1.75, 101.75, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [2.0, 2.0, 102.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [2.25, 2.25, 2.25, 102.25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 102.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [2.75, 2.75, 2.75, 2.75, 2.75, 102.75, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 103.0, 0, 0, 0],
 [3.25, 3.25, 3.25, 3.25, 3.25, 3.25, 3.25, 103.25, 0, 0],
 [3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 103.5, 0],
 [3.75, 3.75, 3.75, 3.75, 3.75, 3.75, 3.75, 3.75, 3.75, 103.75])
```

I am trying to do a loop that would meet these requirements.  For instance:

```
value1 = 96.6/105.5
value2 = (93.71-1.75*value1)/101.75
value3 = (91.56-2*value1-2*value2)/102
...
value10 = (98.14-3.75*value1-3.75*value2-3.75*value3-3.75*value4-
    3.75*value5-3.75*value6-3.75*value7-3.75*value8-3.75*value9-3.75*. 
    value10)/103.75
```

Can anyone help me do this? I am trying to get an array with these 10 results.

Cheers!

Comment: I am wondering if this is a typo: `value1 = 96.6/105.5`? Should it be maybe: `value1 = 96.6/101.5`?

Comment: What do you mean by 96.5/105.5 ? Please explain better.

Comment: Sorry! value 1 through 10 are the results that I am looking for. 

For insntance the first value of the array, value 1, should be 96.6/105.5, 

then it loops for value 2 the result should be (93.71-1.75*value1)/101.75. 

This would loop until value 10 = (98.14-3.75*value1-3.75*value2-3.75*value3-3.75*value4-3.75*value5-3.75*value63.75*value7-3.75*value8-3.75*value9-3.75*. value10)/103.75

Hope this makes more sense!

Comment: @BernardoRaimundo Could you please clarify where `105.5` is coming from?

Comment: What happened when you tried to write a loop that does what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new array, and just dot product it with the row of `b` array. And yes make sure that you initialize the final result array with zeros.

```py
In [115]: val_arr = np.zeros((10,1))
     ...: for i in range(len(a)):
     ...:     val_arr[i] = (a[i] - np.dot(b[i],val_arr))/max(b[i])
In [116]: val_arr
Out[116]: 
array([[0.95172414],
       [0.90461408],
       [0.86124827],
       [0.8227426 ],
       [0.78916271],
       [0.76042723],
       [0.73611886],
       [0.71559687],
       [0.69849544],
       [0.68423626]])
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers this is exactly the results I was expecting!

Answer (score 0):

There is for sure a more efficient way but I used loops because you asked for it explicitly.

**Assumption**

Array `a` has the same length as `b` has rows.

**Input**

```
a = np.array([96.6, 93.71, 91.56, 90.24, 89.74, 90.04, 91.09, 92.82, 95.19, 98.14])

b = np.array([[101.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1.75, 101.75, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [2.0, 2.0, 102.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [2.25, 2.25, 2.25, 102.25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 102.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [2.75, 2.75, 2.75, 2.75, 2.75, 102.75, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 103.0, 0, 0, 0],
 [3.25, 3.25, 3.25, 3.25, 3.25, 3.25, 3.25, 103.25, 0, 0],
 [3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 103.5, 0],
 [3.75, 3.75, 3.75, 3.75, 3.75, 3.75, 3.75, 3.75, 3.75, 103.75]])
```

**Solution**

```
result = [(v-np.sum([b[i][j]*a[j]/b[i][i] for j in range(i)]))/b[i][i] for i, v in enumerate(a)]
result = np.array(result) # convert the list into an array
```

**Output**

```
print(result)
[0.9517241379310344, 0.9046542991506136, 0.8610630526720492, 0.8218824612478405, 0.7869672813801308, 0.7560004972738738, 0.7283061551512867, 0.7029629065070441, 0.6793031342621765, 0.6564261866744086]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers this is exactly the results I was expecting!